# Using cts query to retrieve collections associated with the given document uri- Marklogic

Tags: json, xquery, marklogic

I need to retrieve the collections to which a given document belongs in Marklogic.
I know xdmp command does that. But I need to use it in cts query to retrieve the data and then filter records from it.

```
xdmp:document-get-collections("uri of document") can't be run inside cts-query to give appropriate data.
```

Any idea how can it be done using cts query?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few options come to mind:

**Option One:** Use [cts:values()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:values)

```
cts:values(cts:collection-reference())
```

If you check out the documentation, you will see that you can also restrict this to certain fragments by passing a query as one of the parameters.

**Update: [11-10-2017]
The comment attached to this asked for a sample of restricting the results of cts:values() to a single document(for practical purposes, I will say fragment == document)

The documentation for cts:values explains this. It is the 4th parameter - a query to restrict the results. Get to know this pattern as it is part of many features of MarkLogic. It is your friend. The query I would use for this problem statement would be a cts:document-query();

An Example:

```
cts:values(
  cts:collection-reference(), 
  (), 
  (), 
  cts:document-query('/path/to/my/document')
)
```

Full Example:

```
cts:search(
    collection(),
    cts:collection-query(
        cts:values(
          cts:collection-reference(), 
          (), 
          (), 
          cts:document-query('/path/to/my/document')
       )
    )
)[1 to 10]
```

**Option two:** use [cts:collection-match()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:collection-match)
Need more control over returning just some of the collections from a document, then use cts:colection-match(). Like the first option, you can restrict the results to just some fragments. However, it has the benefit of having an option for a pattern.

---

Attention:
They both return a  sequence - perfect for feeding into other parts of your query. However, under the hood, I believe they work differently. The second option is run against a lexicon. The larger the list of unique collection names and the more complex your pattern match, the longer for resolution. I use collection-match in projects. However, I usually use it when I can limit the possible choices by restricting the results to a smaller number of documents.

Comment: Thanks David for response. I still can't figure out how collection-reference can be used to get collections associated with a document (using its doument uri like xdmp:document-get-collection).Using cts:collection-match() I can filter out collections that I understood. 
Can you provide sample query if possible. Thanks

Comment: Dear user with the fancy name user1575601, I have updated the example for cts:values to retrieve all collections for a single document.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in a single step. You have to run code first to retrieve collections associated with a document. You can use something like xdmp:document-get-collections for that. You then have to feed that into a cts query that you build dynamically:

```
let $doc-collections := xdmp:document-get-collections($doc-uri)
return
  cts:search(collection(), cts:collection-query($doc-collections))[1 to 10]
```

HTH!

Comment: Geert, one could do this in a single query by providing the results of either cts:collection-match or cts:values as the input to your cts:collection-query.

Comment: That is not really a single step. It makes two rounds to resolve against indexes.

Comment: Ahh.. good point. Now Im interested.. Going to (offline) test the various scenerios to see if there is any performance differences.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [cts:collection-query()](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:collection-query)?

Comment: cts:collection-query retrieves documents associated within that collection. I am looking vice versa, getting collections for document.

Answer (score 1):

Insert two XML files to the same collection:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
xdmp:document-insert("/a.xml", <root><sub1><a>aaa</a></sub1></root>,
map:map() => map:with("collections", ("coll1")));

xdmp:document-insert("/b.xml", <root><sub2><a>aaa</a></sub2></root>,
map:map() => map:with("collections", ("coll1")));
```

Search the collection:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $myColl:= xdmp:document-get-collections("/a.xml")
return 
    cts:search(/root,
    cts:and-query((cts:collection-query($myColl),cts:element-query(xs:QName("a"),"aaa")
)))
```